# Sort python dictionary with list as value

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary with list of values:-

```
dict_test = {
        'TYPE'          :       [ 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5' ],
        'MARK'          :       [ 8, 11, 5, 34, 2 ]
}
```

I am trying to sort by key: `MARK`

I got below approach from one of the previous post:-

```
>>> dict((k,sorted(v)) for k, v in dict_test.items())
{'TYPE': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'], 'MARK': [2, 5, 8, 11, 34]}
```

But I noticed that this approach sorted the key: `MARK` values, but it didn't sort the key: `TYPE` value accordingly.

E.g. `TYPE: S1` is mapped to `MARK: 8` initially. But after sort, `TYPE: S1` is mapped to `MARK: 2`

So what should I do to make sure if I sort key: `MARK` it will adjust the order of key: `TYPE` values as well?

Comment: If type `'S1'` has to be mapped to 8, shouldn't it be like `{'S1': 8}` to start with?

Comment: I am creating the dictionary in like this:- `dict_test['TYPE'].append('S1'); dict_test['MARK'].append(8)` So I don't have any issue with mapping initially. But I can't sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sorted list of `(MARK, TYPE)` pairs. Then update your dictionary:

```
z = sorted(zip(dict_test['MARK'], dict_test['TYPE']))
dict_test['TYPE'] = [tup[1] for tup in z]
dict_test['MARK'] = [tup[0] for tup in z]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra function to get sorted index first and then apply it to your values of dict.

For instance:

```
# Sort MARK 
idxes = sorted(range(len(dict_test['MARK'])), key=lambda i: dict_test['MARK'][i])

dict_test['TYPE'] = [dict_test['TYPE'][i] for i in idxes]
dict_test['MARK'] = [dict_test['MARK'][i] for i in idxes]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most pythonic approach but this should do the trick.

```
diction = {mark: type for mark, type in zip(dict_test['MARK'], dict_test['TYPE'])}

sorted_dict_test = {'TYPE': [], 'MARK': []}

for i in sorted(diction.items()):
    sorted_dict_test['MARK'].append(i[0])
    sorted_dict_test['TYPE'].append(i[1])
```

For python 3.7+:

Please note that since the `diction` dictionary is built using `int` keys, it is already sorted ascending and we do not need to use `sorted(diction.items())`. We can simply loop over the dictionary and build the `sorted_dict_test`